# Today Extension Not Displaying Properly

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, widget, nsnotificationcenter

I have been using http://blog.xebia.com/2014/09/13/ios-today-widget-written-in-swift/#comment-328295 to try and get a Today Extension added to my blog, and for the life of me, I cannot figure out what is going wrong.  I follow all the steps, and my widget just shows as one line, not displaying the TableView at all in it.  I even downloaded their github project, and copied the files from it to my project, and it still messed up.  No clue where I am messing up at.  You can check out my source file at http://www.316apps.com/Testing.zip

Thanks

Comment: Really need some help with this, driving me nuts that even copying and pasting isn't helping.  I have to be missing something but I've done it time and time again with same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try setting your contentHeight manually in *widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler*?

```
// width is ignored
self.preferredContentSize = NSSize(width: 0, height: 300)
```